# Making a custom Model table of 2 columns in magento

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, magento

I setup a Model on my module COMPANY/Shippingagent
my config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
...
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
...
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Shippingagent>
                <class>COMPANY_Shippingagent_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>Shippingagent_Mysql4</resourceModel>
            </Shippingagent>
            <Shippingagent_mysql4>
                <class>COMPANY_Shippingagent_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <Shippingagent>
                        <table>Shippingagent</table>
                    </Shippingagent>
                </entities>
            </Shippingagent_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <Shippingagent_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>COMPANY_Shippingagent</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Shippingagent_setup>
            <Shippingagent_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Shippingagent_write>
            <Shippingagent_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Shippingagent_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

On my Layout I placed

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
            ->setTemplate('company/shipping_template.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

The template looks like

```
<div class="input-box" align= right>
    <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" id="shipAgent" >
    <input type="button" id="newship" value="Add New Agent" >
</div>
<script>
jQuery("#newship").click(function() {
    //console.log('test');
    var jsonObject = {};
    jsonObject.brand = jQuery("#shipAgent").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/shippingagent/Agent/setAgent',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{
            json: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
        },
        success:function(data){
            jQuery('#success').html("Success");
            jQuery('#success').css('color', 'green');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    public function setAgentAction() {
        $json = $this->getRequest()->getParam('json');
        $json = json_decode($json);
        foreach($json as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 'brand')
            $brand = $v;
    }
//Send $json to the model
        $data = array(
                'title'=>$brand
                      );
        $model = Mage::getModel('COMPANY_Shippingagent/Shippingagent')->setData($data);

       try {
            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
            echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();   
        }
    }
}
```

My model looks like this:

```
class COMPANY_Shippingagent_Model_Mysql4_Shippingagent extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {  
        $this->_init('Shippingagent/Shippingagent', 'Shippingagent_id');
    }
}
```

And my table looks like this:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('COMPANY_Shippingagent/Shippingagent')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('COMPANY_Shippingagent/Shippingagent')} (
  `Shippingagent_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Shippingagent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

I am getting an error passing in the value with json and the table is never created. 
I don't know what I am doing wrong but I suspect that the problem is in my controller after the $data declaration since when I  comment all that section and echo $brand it actually show me the value I want to add to the table. 
Any ideas? I am going crazy here...

Comment: Creating the table should not be dependent on the rest of the code. The setup script should run prior to any routing. Did you mean 'did not insert to the table'?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Did you check your database whether table has been created or not. if not then delete setup entry from core_resource table of your database then so when you will make any refresh in admin panel script file would run again,however you can try echo exit in installation script in order to make sure. I can see their is problem with installation script file could u please have look at way the you get table name function

Comment: It was fixed. It seems like it was a problem with the xml file in config.xml